# How do I get a translucent view to float over my table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make a summary box at the top of the screen that remains there while below it you have a table view.  When you scroll the tableview I'd like it to be visible but blurry through the summary box, rather like the status bar along the top.

So I've created a view with two subviews - one for the summary and one for the tableview, which works.  I've set the summary view to be transparent and you can see the table view behind it.  Unfortunately, the top cell in the table view is obscured.

So my question is - can I add a vertical offset so the top cell starts below the summary box?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve what I want - a box that stays at the top of the table as you scroll up and down, and is transparent/translucent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the top content inset of the table view to the height of the floating view:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
insets.top = floatingView.frame.size.height;
tableView.contentInset = insets;
```

`UITableView` inherits `contentInset` property from `UIScrollView`.

Comment: That's the ticket!  Is there a way of doing that in interface builder?

Comment: Click to select your UITableView. 
Right Toolbar > Size Inspector (the ruler icon towards the top) > ScrollView Size Tab > Scroll Indicators. There's a textField for insets.

Comment: There is indeed, but only for Indicator Insets, not Content Insets (I don't know what an indicator is, but I tried editing that and it didn't work).

Comment: Ah, also I've just realised this look a bit pants without blurring, and all the solutions I've found for that look pretty complicated.

Why can't they just allow you to fully customize the top toolbar?

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927266/77567) interesting if you want a blur effect.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Rob.  I won't implement it now as I don't want to put too much effort into something that won't work on iPhone 4s or older, but if I have time later I might!  Was thinking about rewriting in Swift as well...

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what you're asking for, but I think you want a transparent fixed header.

Rob Mayoff's way should work- Adding a subview to the tableview, and setting the tableview's `contentInsets` to the height of that subview should what I think you want. But I'll suggest an alternative- using the section headers built in to the UITableView control.

Try this- (a very basic implementation of a fixed section header for a tableview with one section)

(make sure your UITableView's delegate and dataSource are set to your view controller)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,320,100}];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    view.alpha = 0.6;
    return view;
}
```

Comment: One caveat of the section header- it will stay fixed as you scroll down through the content, but will lock to the top of the content view.

Comment: Yeah, that would bounce down with the content wouldn't it?  What I'm after is really not part of the table - it's a statically positioned area at the top of the screen, it will actually remain there even when the tableview has segued to something else (what happens in the table view and other controller affects what happens in the top section).  Kinda like a menu bar, but instead of a menu it's just displaying data.