# Add blur in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying get a snapshot of a UICollectionViewCell, blur it and add as a subview to the UICollectionViewCell.

Some weird problems are happening.

```
MyCollectionViewController

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell<MyCollectionViewCellProtocol> *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.modelVariable = self.modelsArray[indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}



@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell <MyCollectionViewCellProtocol>

@property (strong, nonatomic) Promo *modelVariable;

@end


#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h" // from WWDC 2013
#import "UIView+Snapshot.h" // My category to create a snapshot from a UIView
@implementation PromoRowCollectionViewCell

- (void)setModelVariable:(ModelVariableClass *)modelVariable
{
    _modelVariable = modelVariable;

    // just settings other stuff that is importante to the cell view
    self.mainImageView.image = modelVariable.mainImage;
    self.titleLabel.text = modelVariable.title;
    self.shortDescriptionLabel.text = modelVariable.detailedDescription;

    // removing the snapshot before taking other snapshot
    // or in case the cell is reused and this modelVariable is not in BlurState
    [self.blurImageView removeFromSuperview];
    self.blurImageView = nil;
    [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
    self.myView = nil;

    if (modelVariable.state == BlurState) {
        // Attempt 1
//        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
//        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
//        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // Attempt 2
//        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
//        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
//        UIImage *imgage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // This was just a test that showed weird behavior
//        UIView *snapshotView = [self snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
//        self.myView = snapshotView;
//        snapshotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
//        CGRect frame = snapshotView.frame;
//        frame.origin = CGPointMake(20, 20);
//        snapshotView.frame = frame;
//        [self addSubview:snapshotView];

        // Attempt 3 // With the red background and shifting the frame we can see just a red rectangle and not the snapshot
        UIView *snapshotView = [self snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
        snapshotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2]; // Just to see things better

//        self.blockedPromoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; // for attempts 1 and 2

        self.blurImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:snapshotView.snapshotImage.applyLightEffect];

//        self.blurImageView.frame = self.bounds;
        self.blockedPromoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height); // Also to see things better

//        self.blockedPromoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2]; // for attempts 1 and 2

        [self addSubview:self.blurImageView];
    }
}

@end


UIView+Snapshot

- (UIImage *)snapshotImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

Attempt 1:
[image]

Attempt 2:
[image]

Test with weird behavior:
[image]

Attempt 3:
[image]

So as you can see, attempts 1, 2 and 3 it seems they didn't take any snapshot.
I'd expect the red rectangle to have a snapshot of the view in the back.

As for the weird behavior test, I'd expect what can be seen in the image, except for the red rectangle most at front.

Does anyone knows whats going on? Or how to solve it?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I just created a simple project with the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j1mhxj367kzn81y/AADW8ds9NvLMyjUDbn08mOJXa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the afterScreenUpdates flag if you just want your image and text change to come through in the screenshot.

You can just edit the image and text, remove views and save the cell as an image in the standard way:

```
-(UIImage*) takeSnapshot {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Then add the blur and add to your view.

```
if (modelVariable.state == BlurState) {
    UIImage *snapshot = [self takeSnapshot];
    UIImage *blurredImage = [snapshot applyLightEffect];

    self.blurredImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:blurredImage];
    [self.view addSubview:self.blurredImageView];
}
```

Comment: That was my attempt 2... and it didn't capture any image.

Comment: You seem to have a typo there where you spelt 'image' as 'imgage' so it might have not worked because you were initialising the UIImageView with the wrong variable? I've tested this code snippet in my own custom table view cell and it works fine for me.

Comment: I actually had already fixed the typo in the real code =/. But tell me something, why are you adding the subview to self.view? to me self is the cell, so I'm just doing [self addSubview:self.blurredImageView]

Comment: I just added a small project that reproduces the problem. In case you don't want to download the code, just write a comment saying that and I'll copy the code here. I removed the blue part just to make things easier.

Comment: Sorry the self.view was a mistake it should be just self. Also I downloaded your test project and ran it but it worked perfectly for me? I can see the subview being added which is just a snapshot of the cell it's in. Tried on Xcode 5 & Xcode 6 beta 5 on ios 7.1 & 8.

Comment: Did you scroll the collection view? The problem happens when the cells are reused.