# UIVisualEffectView in iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, ios8

Below line of swift code works fine on iOS8 devices and simulators but on iOS7 simulator, gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0.x20) error with (lldb) in log.

```
var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
```

EDIT: Since this class is not available in iOS7, I have put this declaration inside an if block and only run it if iOS version is 8+ but now it throws unresolved identifier error elsehwere in the code where i am trying to remove this blur effect view (even though, I am checking if it was created):

```
if iosVersion >= 8 {
   blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0) @interface UIVisualEffectView

Comment: You mean, this class is not available in iOS7? Is there an alternative i can use?

Comment: Yes, it is not available in iOS7, there are UIImage+BlurEffect class from apple sample code, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927178/standard-ios-7-blur-implementation

Comment: thanks. i have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: use of unresolved identifier 'blurEffectView'

Comment: You should declare `blurEffectView` as a global variable.

Comment: i tried moving the declaration to outside the function to make it global but then it throws the original error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0.x20) when trying to run on ios7 simulator. If I try to wrap it inside the if iosVersion >= 8 {} it throws error, 'expected declaration'.

Comment: Depending how you declare it, you may want to add ! or ? at the end.

Comment: Thank you, that finally fixed the problem. The trick was to declare it optional but as AnyObject, so iOS 7 will not have any problem with it. Later, conditionally (if iOS8) you change it to UIVisualEffectView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as guided by @gabbler was to declare it optional as AnyObject. Then conditionally (if iOS8) change it to UIVisualEffectView.